# Write to python csv in whileloop

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to log some data with python and I want it to save a datapoint into a text file at every iteration.

So currently I have

```
while true:
    light = ReadChannel(light)
    voltage =  ConvertVoltage(light)
    print(light, voltage)
    time.delay(5)
```

So the print would ideally become a write command. 
I've checked the site but nothing seems to support a while loop write command (as it opens and closes it constantly).

Comment: It doesn't matter much in this case, but please try to post *working* code. `true` should be `True`, the first use of `light` is undefined, `time.delay` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to open the file handle and instanciate the CSV writer *outside* your loop, but write to it *inside* the loop:

```
import csv
import time

HEADER = ['LIGHT', 'VOLTAGE']

# ...


def processing_loop(csvfile):
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(HEADER)

    # ...
    while True:
        light = ReadChannel(light)
        voltage =  ConvertVoltage(light)
        csv_writer.writerow([light, voltage])
        csvfile.flush()
        time.sleep(5)


with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    processing_loop(csvfile)
```

For easier reading I factored out the loop into its own function that takes one argument, an open file handle that it can use to create the CSV writer with.

Also note the `csvfile.flush()` - this is necessary if you want the data to be written to the file immediately upon every iteration. Otherwise it would only be writen once the file is closed (when you exit the `with` block, i.e. terminate the script).

Comment: It tells me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grav.py", line 45, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow([light, voltage])
NameError: name 'csv_writer' is not defined
`

Comment: So something in that function is going wrong I think :P

Comment: Well, if you use the code as I posted it, it is defined.  So you must have tried to take it apart, and omitted the definition of `csv_writer`.

Comment: I spread it out a bit to accommodate the rest of the code :P But I don't think that I changed it further. 
http://pastebin.com/K19iCrQi

Comment: Mmh, yes you did. You took out the loop of the `processing_loop()` function again, and put it into the main scope. Move line 34 - 53 into the `processing_loop()` function (after the definition of `csv_writer`), and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by saying that nothing supports writing inside a loop. That is of course the usual way to do things: you open the file outside the loop, write to it consecutively inside the loop, then close it afterwards.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    while True:
        light = whatever
        voltage = whatever
        writer.writerow([light, voltage])
```